# HalconDotNet - Converting HtupleVector to int in C#

Tags: c#, halcon

From my Halcon procedure I receive a HtupleVector with coordinates that looks like:

`{{[900, 200], [300, 200], [600, 700], [1000, 700], [200, 700]}}`

I want to use these values in C# as integers so I tried the following:

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < coordList.Length; i++)
{
  var x = coordList[i][0]; // crashes process
  var y = coordList[i][1]; // crashes process

  var x2 = snapped_coords[i].At(0); // crashes process
  var y2 = snapped_coords[i].At(1); // crashes process

  var x3 = snapped_coords.At(i).At(0); // crashes process
  var y4 = snapped_coords.At(i).At(1); // crashes process
}
```

How can I extract values from a HTupleVector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work:

```cs
var coordTuple = coordList[i].ConvertVectorToTuple();
int x = (int)coordTuple[0].D;
int y = (int)coordTuple[1].D;
```